Can I use vectors to evaluate the mass of the object in the following problem with the specified coordinate system?
An object attached to the end of a string swings in a vertical circle (R = 1.2 m), as shown. At an instant when θ = 30°, the speed of the object is 5.1 m/s and the tension in the string has a magnitude of 20 N. What is the mass of the object?

First I established a coordinate system with its center at the center of the circle in the image, an x-axis as the horizontal line which the angle rises from in the image with the positive numbers to the right of the center, and a y-axis perpendicular to the x-axis with the positive numbers going upward toward the top of the image.
I then wrote a net force vector which is the centripetal force needed for the object to remain in circular motion and has magnitude $\frac{mv^2}{R}$. I then decomposed the tension and force of gravity into their x and y components to get the following vector and equation.
$$\vec T = -T\left\langle \cos(θ) , \sin(θ) \right\rangle $$
$$\vec F_c = -\frac{mv^2}{R} \left\langle \cos(θ) , \sin(θ) \right\rangle $$
$$\vec F_g = \left\langle 0,-mg \right\rangle $$
$$\vec F_c = \vec F_{net} = \vec F_g + \vec T$$
Setting the x-components and the y-components of the centripetal force and net force vectors equal to each other, I get the following two equations:
$$ \sum{F_x} = -T\cos(θ) + 0 = -\frac{mv^2}{R}\cos(θ) $$
$$ \sum{F_y} = -T\sin(θ) -mg = -\frac{mv^2}{R}\sin(θ) $$
Solving the x-equation:
$$ m = \frac{TR}{v^2} = \frac{(20N)(1.2m)}{(5.1m/s)^2} = 0.92kg $$
Solving the y-equation:
$$ m = \frac{TR\sin(θ)}{v^2\sin(θ)-Rg} = \frac{(20N)(1.2m)\sin(30°)}{(5.1m/s)^2\sin(30°) - (1.2m)(9.8m/s^2)} = 9.7kg $$
$$ 0.92kg \neq 9.7kg $$
When I solve for the mass in these equations I get two different values, 0.92kg for the x-equation and 9.7kg for the y-equation. I checked on Chegg and they said the mass is 1.2kg. Their solution involved setting their axis along the line of centripetal force. I am aware that their solution is much simpler but I want to know why the way I'm doing it is not yielding the correct answer and if it is even possible to get the correct answer the way I did it. thank you
Also are there any softwares where I can make simple diagrams like the one in the pic? If the answer could include a simple diagram to show why mine doesn't work that would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: After reading DanDan面's comment I realized I had failed to consider that the gravitational force had both radial and tangential components and in the above calculations I had not separated the gravitational force into said calculations. The following diagrams show how the gravitational force is decomposed into its radial and tangential components, and then how said components are shown as vectors by further decomposing them into their x and y components. The θ' symbol represents the complement of θ such that $θ' = 90° - θ$.

The gravitational force can now be written as a sum of its radial(centripetal) and tangential components:
$$ \vec F_g = \vec F_{gc} + \vec F_{gt} = -mg\left\langle \sin(θ)\cos(θ), \sin^2(θ) \right\rangle + mg\left\langle  \sin(θ)\cos(θ), -\cos^2(θ) \right\rangle = \left\langle  0,-mg \right\rangle$$
To find the mass of the object, we only need to use the radial component of the gravitational force, although the tangential form is also useful in checking our work. Given that the radial and tangential components of both gravity and the net force in each direction respectively are perpendicular, the following statements must be true:
$$ \sum \vec F_c \cdot \sum \vec F_t = 0 $$
$$ \vec F_{gc} \cdot \vec F_{gt} = 0 $$
To ensure we calculated the direction of the radial component of the gravitational force correctly, we can use the cross-product to ensure that it is parallel to the tension vector (the cross-product of parallel vectors is zero, just append an extra zero to each as shown below)
$$\vec F_{gc} × \vec T = \vec 0 $$
$$ -mg\left\langle \sin(θ)\cos(θ), \sin^2(θ), 0 \right\rangle
× -T\left\langle \cos(θ), \sin(θ), 0 \right\rangle = \vec 0 $$
With the radial component of the gravitational force, we can now evaluate the mass of the object in the same way I had attempted originally, if it is correct the quantity should be the same regardless of whether evaluated from the x or y component.
$$\vec F_c = \vec F_{gc} + \vec T$$
$$ \sum{F_x} = -mg\sin(θ)\cos(θ) -T\cos(θ) = -\frac{mv^2}{R}\cos(θ) $$
$$ \sum{F_y} = -mg\sin^2(θ) -T\sin(θ) = -\frac{mv^2}{R}\sin(θ) $$
Solving either of the equations for m yields the same result:
$$ m = \frac{TR}{v^2-Rg\sin(θ)} = \frac{(20N)(1.2m)}{(5.1m/s)^2-(1.2m)(9.8m/s^2)\sin(30°)} = 1.2kg$$

You are assuming that there is no tangential acceleration, only centripetal acceleration. This is not true. The object will speed up as it travels downwards.
